Splotchy and messed up print with varying line widths on prusa printer
I'm trying to use my 3D printer for this wallet with my Prusa MK3S+ but on the 2nd and 3rd layers, it gets messed up as the picture shows. The first layer looks fine so I'm not sure what's wrong or what to adjust.

